# Regex for character range and space

Tags: java, regex

I use the following to check if a given string `unicodeName` is within a certain character range:

```
unicodeName.matches(".*[^\u1000-\u103f].*")
```

However, this does not allow for the inclusion of space characters in the name. If I want the user to type space in the name and at the same time want the matcher to return true what would the regex be?

Example:

This works fine for me

[image: works]

but this doesn't

[image]

Comment: Any example to help us?

Comment: `.*` allows any amount of spaces. Please clarify what you need.

Comment: I think you want `[ \u1000-\u103f]*`.  Maybe you could trim the string after, and if need check its length to ensure input wasn't just whitespace or empty.

Comment: @Thomas I have updated the question to give examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
^[\\s\\u1000-\\u103f]*$
```

(don't forget to escape `\`)

Comment: What can you say about OP's regex? I thought it should match anything due to `.*` pattern.

Comment: @Sloth note the `^` in the group

Comment: I actually used `.*[^က-ဿ\s].*`

Comment: @SandahAung with your example, the user can input `abc def`, isn't it? And also `lqksdjfmqlsdkfhlqkjnzoiegzepghmdsklfjmg65478614351 sqijfgoe` ... Which is not what you want...?

Comment: Amazingly it doesn't accept `abc def`. Nor does it accept `lqksdjfmqlsdkfhlqkjnzoiegzepghmdsklfjmg65478614351 sqijfgoe`.

Comment: well, it *should*... @SandahAung

Answer (score 1):

Following regex work for me

```
[A-Za-z\\\s]*
```

Comment: Did you try it on given example?